# How to organize Electron.js renderer code across multiple files without compromising security?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm building an **Electron.js** application, and I have been reading the documentation on context isolation, the main and renderer processes, and more.

I am struggling to understand how I can organize my renderer process code into multiple files or classes without using other frameworks such as Angular or Vue.

I have more or less achieved this goal by setting the `sandbox` option to `false`, which allows me to use `require` for external modules that are not part of Electron. However, as far as I understand, this is not a best practice because it poses security risks. Additionally, I encountered difficulties with classes when using this option. *With only functions it works.*

Here is the code that is giving me errors. How can I organize my renderer code into multiple files without going crazy?

**main.js**

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, dialog, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const nodePath = require("path");

function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      sandbox: false,
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  });

  win.loadFile('index.html');
}

ipcMain.handle('open-dialog', async (event, arg) => {
  const result = await dialog.showOpenDialog({
    properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections']
  });

  return result;
});

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

**preload.js**

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const Test = require('./test');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myAPI', {
    Test: Test
});
```

**renderer.js**

```js
const api = window.myAPI;

const button = document.querySelector('#hi');
button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const test = new api.Test();
    test.hi();
});
```

**test.js**  *file where I put the functions or classes to be exported*

```js
class Test {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "TheSmith1222";
    }
    hi(){
        console.log("Hi, " + this.name);
    }
}

module.exports = {
  Test
};
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self';">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <button id="hi">Hi</button>
    <script src="./renderer.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Output button onclick:**

```
renderer.js:5 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: api.Test is not a constructor
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (renderer.js:5:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `preload.js` script does not need to play a part when organising / loading additional render process scripts.

I have found that having a single `renderer.js` file (loaded into your html file via a `<script>` tag) manages the different types of imports, being class and method only files. That said, I am sure there are other ways you can structure this if you like.

I have included code for the 5 files listed below:

- main.js (main process)
- index.html (render process)
- renderer.js (render process)
- test-1.js (render process)
- test-2.js (render process)

I have excluded your `preload.js` script as its contents and general implementation does not affect this issue.

---

`main.js` (main process)

A minimal implementation to get things working.

```js
// Import required electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

// Import required Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            sandbox: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

---

`index.html` (render process)

For testing purposes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <button id="hi-1">Hi (Class)</button>
        <button id="hi-2">Hi (Function)</button>
    </body>

    <script type="module" src="./renderer.js"></script>
</html>
```

---

`renderer.js` (render process)

Import your different render support files for use by the `html` page.

```js
import {Test1} from './test-1.js'; // Class
import {test_2_hi} from './test-2.js'; // Method(s)

const test_1 = new Test1();

document.getElementById('hi-1').addEventListener('click', () => {
    test_1.hi();
})

document.getElementById('hi-2').addEventListener('click', () => {
    test_2_hi();
})
```

---

`test-1.js` (render process)

Use of a class.

```js
class Test1 {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Test 1 (Class)';
    }

    hi() {
        console.log('Hi from ' + this.name);
    }
}

export {Test1};
```

---

`test-2.js` (render process)

Use of a standard function.

```js
let name = 'Test 2 (Function)';

function test_2_hi() {
    console.log('Hi from ' + name);
}

export {test_2_hi};
```